# Mosquitto Auth Plugin with Openssl issue on raspberry pi

Tags: authentication, openssl, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I have first created a user for mosquitto:

```
sudo adduser --system -no-create-home mosquitto
```

Then I installed some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libc-ares-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then I installed mosquitto:

```
wget http://mosquitto.org/files/source/mosquitto-1.3.5.tar.gz //download mosquitto-1.3.5
tar xvzf mosquitto-1.3.5.tar.gz //unzip tar file
```

Then `cd mosquitto-1.3.5`

Then I put config.mk in edit mode using

```
 sudo nano config.mk
```

Then I searched for `SRV` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
Changed `With_SRV:=no`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit out of file

Now I need to install Openssl to build mosquitto.

So I installed Openssl using this command:

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0c.tar.gz
```

Download md5 file to generate md5 code

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0c.tar.gz.md5
```

Generate md5sum

```
md5sum openssl-1.0.0c.tar.gz
```

Generate md5 code

```
cat openssl-1.0.0c.tar.gz.md5
```

if both code matches than we have downloaded the file completely

unzip the tar file

```
tar -xvzf openssl-1.1.0c.tar.gz 54. cd openssl-1.1.0c
```

Configure the openssl before compiling it

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl
```

Compile openssl

```
make
```

Install Openssl

```
sudo make install
```

The above line gives error, so the below line of code:

```
sudo make install_sw
```

Verify if openssl was installed successfully

```
/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl version //get the version number of openssl
```

Come out of the directory and go to the directory of mosquitto:

```
cd
cd mosquitto-1.3.5
```

Install another dependency of mosquitto

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Compile Mosquitto

```
sudo make
```

Install Mosquitto:

```
sudo make install
```

download mosquitto auth plugin from github

```
git clone https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug.git
```

Download hiredis

```
git clone https://github.com/redis/hiredis.git
```

Go to hiredis directory and compile it and install it

```
cd hiredis
make
sudo make install
```

Go to mosquitto auth plugin directory

```
cd
cd mosquitto-1.3.5
cd mosquitto-auth-plug
```

Copy the contents of config.mk.in to config.mk

```
cp config.mk.in config.mk
```

Open config.mk in edit mode

```
sudo nano config.mk
```

Change these lines of code:

```
MOSQUITTO_SRC = /home/pi/mosquitto-1.3.5
OPENSSLDIR = /usr/local/openssl
```

Save the file and come out of it

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> then
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit

Then I try to compile mosquitto-auth-plug:

```
make
```

At this time I get this error:

```
Selected backends:          MySQL
Using mosquitto source dir: /home/pi/mosquitto-1.3.5
OpenSSL install dir:        /usr/local/openssl

If you changed the backend selection, you might need to 'make clean' first

CFLAGS:  -I/home/pi/mosquitto-1.3.5/src/ -I/home/pi/mosquitto-1.3.5/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_MYSQL  -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing    -g -DNDEBUG -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/local/openssl/include
LDFLAGS:  -L/home/pi/mosquitto-1.3.5/lib/
LDADD:    -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl -L/usr/local/openssl/lib -lcrypto -lmosquitto

cc -I/home/pi/mosquitto-1.3.5/src/ -I/home/pi/mosquitto-1.3.5/lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror  -DBE_MYSQL  `mysql_config --cflags` -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/local/openssl/include   -c -o cache.o cache.c
cache.c: In function ‘sha_hash’:
cache.c:48:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘EVP_MD_CTX_new’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
   ^
cache.c:48:23: error: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
   EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
                       ^
cache.c:53:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘EVP_MD_CTX_free’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);
   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
<builtin>: recipe for target 'cache.o' failed
make: *** [cache.o] Error 1
```

So, I removed openssl-1.0.0c and installed openssl-1.1.0c version

Then compiling of mosquitto-auth-plug is done successfully

Then move the files as follows:

```
sudo mv auth-plug.so /etc/mosquitto
sudo mv /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.example /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

edit mosquitto .conf file

```
sudo nano /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to search

search for auth_plugin and write below mentioned commands after the second occurance of auth_plugin

```
auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so
auth_opt_backends mysql
auth_opt_redis_host localhost
auth_opt_redis_port 12885
auth_opt_host localhost
auth_opt_port 3306
auth_opt_dbname HAC
auth_opt_user mqtt_user
auth_opt_pass ###YOUR_PASSWORD###
auth_opt_userquery SELECT pw FROM mqtt_users WHERE username = '%s'
auth_opt_superquery SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mqtt_users WHERE username = '%s' AND super = 1
auth_opt_aclquery SELECT topic FROM mqtt_acls WHERE (username = '%s') AND (rw >= %d)
auth_opt_anonusername AnonymouS
```

Then save the file by presssing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

To exit out of the file press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Then when I run this command:

/usr/local/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

I get the following error:

```
1486888881: mosquitto version 1.3.5 (build date 2017-02-11 22:22:57+0000) starting
1486888881: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1486888881: Error: Unable to load auth plugin "/etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so".
```

Can anybody help me please?

I have already wasted 4 days in searching a solution of this error.

**Update:**

I have uninstalled mosquitto and installed its latest version. Still getting the same error but its more descriptive this time. Now it says:

```
mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date 2017-02-13 22:22:57+0000) starting
Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
Error: Unable to load auth plugin "/etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so".
Load Error: /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so: Undefined Symbol: EVP_MD_CTX_reset
```

Comment: first question, Why are you building mosquitto 1.3.5? the latest is 1.4.10

Comment: @hardillb I am trying to learn mqtt using mosquitto and for that I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-x6E_rBMvai4l2akwY-VaQOto5rm7p7Q Once I complete that then I will think about the latest versions and all. BTW a big thank you for replying to this post. Still I will try to use new version of mosquitto and openssl to check if my problem is solved.

Comment: It s not really clear to me what issue you are trying to work on. Do you want to pursue the OpenSSL 1.0.0 build issues? Or the  auth-plug.so issue? Maybe you should narrow your question a bit. Perhaps you should refer to [mosquitto-auth-plug | Issue 135: Cannot Load auth-plug.so](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug/issues/135).

Comment: @jww I just want that auth-plugin should work for me. I don't care if it works with openssl 1.0.0 or openssl 1.1.0. I have tried both and in both versions I get different errors. So, I mentioned it in question. So that anybody can diagnose the cause of my problem.

Comment: @hardillb I have tried your suggestion. Please see update part in question.

Comment: Please try with newest [OpenSSL 1.1.0e available, including bug and security fixes]

Comment: In addition, be advised to recheck version of [libssl-dev] you are using.

Comment: Your `mosquitto.conf` is wrong too. The option keys should be `auth_opt_[backend]_[option name]`, so `auth_opt_mysql_user` not `auth_opt_user`, etc, except for global options. You can drop the redis options since you don't appear to be using redis. 

Also, make sure you have the correct backends compiled in by editing `mosquitto-auth-plug`'s `config.mk` before you `make`.